# Get Alpha/Opacity of Layout

Tags: java, android, user-interface

How do I get the current Alpha/Opacity of Layout? I want the from of my AlphaAnimation to be the current alpha so it doesn't flicker between my fade in and fade out calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to opt for the Get and Set methods in Android 3.0 in future.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layout do you have?  This could work:

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    int opacity = layout.getBackground().getOpacity();
```

Comment: RelativeLayout. Will give that a try now. Did something similar but had an error. Will double check.